# Why are all of my ZFS snapshot directories empty?

Tags: zfs, snapshot, solaris-11

I'm running an Oracle 11 box as a ZFS storage appliance, and I'm taking regular snapshots of the ZFS filesystems, via `cron`.

In the past, I know that if I wanted to grab a particular file from a snapshot, a read-only copy was kept in `.zfs/snapshot/{name}/` and I could just navigate there and pull the file out. This is documented [on Oracle's website](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19082-01/817-2271/gbciq/index.html).

However, I went to do this the other day, and noticed that the ZFS directories within the snapshot directories are all empty. `zfs list -t snapshot` correctly shows the list of snapshots that should be present, and `.zfs/snapshots` correctly contains a directory for each snapshot, and in each snapshot there is a directory present for each ZFS filesystem. However, these directories appear to be empty.

I just tested a restore by touching a file in a little-used share and rolling back to the latest hourly snapshot, and this appears to have worked fine. So the rollback functionality is there.

Did Oracle change how snapshots are done? Or is something seriously wrong here?

Comment: Related: https://groups.google.com/a/zfsonlinux.org/forum/#!topic/zfs-discuss/aAJsQoSY3BQ , https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/issues/1768#issuecomment-27266951 and https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/issues/2841

Comment: And also https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/issues/3030 . Although, you use the Oracle ZFS tree, and they probably have diverted enough to not be directly comparable anymore.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have a descendent ZFS filesystem, for example `tank/newfs`. Then you will not find files in `tank/newfs` in the `/tank/.zfs/mysnapshot` folder, only the mountpoint `newfs` will exist. If you want to access the files you need to look for your files in the `/tank/newfs/.zfs/mysnapshot` folder.

Answer (score 3):

The snapshots listed in `.zfs/snapshot/` are automatically mounted on demand, as they are being browsed, and are automatically unmounted when no longer in use.

Doing a simple `ls` in a directory is apparently not enough to be considered 'demand'. You will need to `cd` into the directory in question and THEN issue the `ls` command.

You may also need to set `snapdir=visible` for the filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

On ZoL (although the original q refers to Solaris), a [bug](https://github.com/openzfs/zfs/issues/9461) currently exists whereby the automount feature described by @Daniel fails to work, resulting in empty snapshot directories.  This seems to happen specifically for a ZFS root filesystem (where snapshots would normally be accessed under `/.zfs/snapshot`).

A telltale sign are entries in `/proc/spl/kstat/zfs/dbgmsg` reading `Unable to automount <snapdir_path> error=512`

Both [workarounds proposed here](https://github.com/openzfs/zfs/issues/9461#issuecomment-699889066) worked for me (I'm running ZoL 2.0.6 on Ubuntu 21.10 and booting through ZFS Boot Menu):

1. Add your ZFS root filesystem mountpoint to `/etc/fstab` (eg: `zpool/ROOT/rootfs / zfs defaults 0 0`) and reboot
2. `mkdir /sysroot && mount -o bind / /sysroot`; the snaps can then be accessed through `/sysroot/.zfs/`

Choose the workaround you prefer (you don't need both).

According to a comment on a [related issue](https://github.com/openzfs/zfs/issues/10104#issuecomment-595790093):

> this error occurs on systems with initramfs which chroot(2)s to new root filesystem and starts init process by running switch_root(8).

Answer (score 0):

The `.zfs/snapshot/my_snapshot` folder will also appear as empty if mounting the snapshot fails.

In my case, running `sudo mount -t zfs tank/my_dataset@my_snapshot /mnt/mountpoint` failed with an Input/Output error that a zfs version upgrade from `0.8.something` to `2.1.5` introduced. See the [github issue](https://github.com/openzfs/zfs/issues/13709#issuecomment-1206586130).